# How to find linear system from a particular general solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Most questions here focus on finding the general solution to a linear system, but what about the other way around?

Can there exist more than one linear system from a single general solution?

Answer (score 1):

The set $S=\{0\}\subset\Bbb R^n$ is the general solution of the system
$$
A\,x=0
$$
for any $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with $\det A\ne0$. So there are infinitely many linear systems with general solution the set $S$.